# UICollectionViewCell IBAction affecting multiple cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` with custom cells that has an `IBAction` attached.  In a nutshell, when a `UIStepper` on the cell is tapped, it increments a value and is displayed in a label on the cell.

This much I have working without much hassle.  The problem is if I scroll enough to load new cells into memory, the cell that match the index of the cell that is modified will display the same incremented value as the original.

```
Cell1 Cell2 Cell3 --scroll-> Cell4 Cell5 Cell6
  0     1     0                0     1     0
```

Cell 5 will match the value of Cell 2 despite not being changed.

```
@IBAction func updateValue(sender: AnyObject) {
    // Code to check if plus or minus
    self.valueLabel = value
}
```

How do I get around this?

**EDIT:**

Cell class

```
protocol ItemCellProtocol {
   fun getValue(value: Double, increment: Bool) -> Double
}

class CustomCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
   @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
   @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel : UILabel!
   @IBOutlet weak var image : UIImage!

   var value = 0
   var delegate : ItemCellProtocol?

   @IBAction func updateQuantity(sender: AnyObject) {
      // Code to check if plus or minus
      self.valueLabel = value

      delegate?.getValue(value, increment: true)
   }
}
```

CollectionViewController

```
class CustomCollectionViewController : UICollectionViewController {
  var overallValue = 0
  items = [item]() // populated during segue of previous VC

  // CollectionView Delegate classes

  func .. cellForItemAtIndexPath {
    let cell = //instance of CustomCollectionViewCell

     let cellItem : Item = self.items[indexPath.row]

     cell.image = cellItem.image

     cell.delegate = self

     return cell
  }

  func getTotal(value: Double, increment: Bool) -> Double {
     if increment {
       self.overallValue += value
     } else {
       self.overallValue -= value
     }
     return self.total
  }
}
```

That's basically how the classes currently work.  I don't have Xcode in front of me currently so I couldn't give the full code.

Comment: Where are you storing the values for your cells? You can't store the value in the cell itself ss cells are reused

Comment: Please add the code for your tableView data source methods. And also where you are incrementing and storing the stepper values.

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionViewCell` will be reused by `UICollectionView` so in your custom cell reset all the state of UI before being reused

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    self.valueLabel.text = "0"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @dopcn.  But wouldn't that reset the original cells value once it goes out of view?

Comment: @Sawyer05 yes it will and that's what collection view data source protocol do